# Make GNU: get letter/char from variable

Tags: makefile, char, gnu-make

I have a variable in a GNU make file :

```
VAR=DDC
```

I want to merge these characters into another string and assign them to a different variable, for example:

```
TOT_VAR=--'D','D','C'--
```

My first idea was to do something like this pseudocode:

```
#Pseudo code
TOT_VAR=--'@(letter1, VAR)','@(letter2, VAR)','@(letter3, VAR)'--
```

But I can't find any function that extracts individual characters.
How might I do this?

Comment: The GNU Make Standard Library http://gmsl.sourceforge.net/ has a `substr` function which might do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` to do the transformation:

```
echo DDC | sed -E "s/^(.{1})(.{1})(.{1}).*/--'\1','\2','\3'--/")
```

What this does:

1. Pipes the string `DDC` to `sed`
2. Tells `sed` to parse the string and match the first three characters
3. Substitute `DDC` for your replacement format, inserting those three characters into the placeholders `\1`, `\2` and `\3`

[If you’re on a Linux OS rather than MacOS like me then I think you’ll need to use `sed -e` rather than `sed -E`]

As the comment from @Maxim says, you'll need to invoke the shell from `make` in order to run this command. Building this approach into a simple makefile to illustrate:

```
VAR=DDC
TOT_VAR:=$(shell echo $(VAR) | sed -E "s/^(.{1})(.{1})(.{1}).*/--'\1','\2','\3'--/")

all:
    echo "$(TOT_VAR)"
```

Running `make all` on this yields this output and shows the substitution has worked:

```
echo "--'D','D','C'--"
--'D','D','C'--
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Right now I´m running on Windows OS. sed -E will not give any output while sed -e gives me DDC as output. I think there is something fishy with the (.{1}) on windows. Looking in to it...

Comment: sed -e "s/\(.\{1\}\)\(.\{1\}\)\(.\{1\}\).*/--'\1','\2','\3'--/") worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has a function `explode` which expands a string into a list:

$(call explode,*stringlist*,*string*)

Insert a blank after every occurrence of the strings from stringlist in string. This function serves mainly to convert a string into a list:

```
$(call explode,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,0x1337c0de) --> 0 x1 3 3 7 c0 de
```

You can access the members of your variable like the following:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk
XPLD_VAR := $(call explode,$([alnum]),$(VAR))
TOT_VAR := --$(word 1,$(XPLD_VAR)),$(word 2,$(XPLD_VAR)),$(word 3,$(XPLD_VAR))--
```